# Reseating the internal hard disk drive

Tags: hard-drive

My Dell Inspiron 1525 says "internal hard disk drive not found. To resolve this issue try to reset the drive."

How do I do this? I have the original hard drive installed, it also says there are no bootable devices.

How do I solve these problems with my laptop? I have no disks for reinstalling drives. Help!

Answer (score 3):

Try taking your drive out and putting it back in again. Ensure the connectors are in firmly. If it still can't physically find it the drive might have failed.

Comment: if that works, does that indicate that the drive is close to failing?

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur if the laptop was bumped hard enough to dislodge the drive connection internally. Often removing and reinserting the drive can solve the issue.

**Always turn off and unplug the computer when performing these tasks.**

On page 25 of the [service manual](http://www.dell.com/support/Manuals/us/en/19/Product/inspiron-1525) are instructions to remove the hard drive.

[image]

To reinstall the drive, reverse the steps.

If the error continues, it is possible the drive has failed.

Answer (score 0):

Reseat the drive means - Removing and then reinstall. You need to unplug the cables and remove it completely and then re connect it again so its detectable, Or you can seek help from a repair shop.

If you have already done reseating and If it's then found, run a full diagnostic (F12 at powerup). But if it's not found or detected by the computer after reseat then its busted.
You can get your previous data back just by contacting the The repair providers.

If you CAN see the drive but not boot from it, remove it, Mount it in a 2.5" external drive case and attach it to a working system to see what you can recover yourself.  Note:  this will ONLY work if the system can see the drive.  If it cannot, you will need a data recovery service.

You can press F2 at startup and check if your hard drive is detected or not. If yes then try to mount it externally. If if still undetectable then you would need a new hard drive (The drive will be replaced under warranty - but data recovery is at your expense.  The warranty does not cover that.)

Hopefully system diagnostic might help

Comment: Note that F2 and F12 may differ per system. Could also be Del, F8 or even F3.

Answer (score 0):

Hit F12 and check if your boot legacy option is OFF, if it is ON change it to OFF then system asks your permission say okay problem solves..

This's how my problem was ended !!

Answer (score -1):

When the screen is  showing some keys like F1 for help, F2 for setup and F5 for PSA, then enter F2 for setup. After select Security. Then showing on screen (UEFI) select UEFI and change it to Legacy and press F10 to save the changes. After that your computer will start.